# MobileFirst 7.1 - Issue with JSONStore Hybrid App when deployed on Android

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I am trying to use JSONStore for one of the requirement.

And as it is hybrid app I configured it by following 
Procedure

Using the Application Descriptor Editor, open the file
  application-descriptor.xml Click the Design tab. Under Overview,
    expand Application [your application's name]. Click Optional
    Features. Click Add. Select JSONStore. Click Ok. In the Project
    Explorer view, right-click the folder that is titled with your
    application name. Click Run As. Click Run on MobileFirst Development
    Server.

Here is the sample code I use to create the document in JSONStore. I followed the instruction given in this [documentation](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_jsonstore_gs_javascript.html).

```
WL.Logger.debug ("Successfully connected to MobileFirst Server.");

    var collectionName = 'SomeFlag';

    if(WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName) == null && WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName) == undefined){      
        // Object that defines all the collections.
        var collections = {

          // Object that defines the 'people' collection.
                userAgreement : {

            // Object that defines the Search Fields for the 'people' collection.
            searchFields : {someFlag: 'boolean'}
          }
        };

        // Optional options object.
        var options = {
          localKeyGen : false
        };

        WL.JSONStore.init(collections, options)

        .then(function () {
          var data = [{someFlag: false}];

          // Optional options for add.
          var addOptions = {

            // Mark data as dirty (true = yes, false = no), default true.
            markDirty: true
          };

          // Get an accessor to the people collection and add data.
          return WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName).add(data, addOptions);
        })

        .then(function (numberOfDocumentsAdded) {
            WL.Logger.debug ("Number Of Documents Added " +numberOfDocumentsAdded);
            alert ("Number Of Documents Added " +numberOfDocumentsAdded);
          // Add was successful.
        })

        .fail(function (errorObject) {
           // Handle failure for any of the previous JSONStore operations (init, add).
            WL.Logger.debug ("JSONStore Failed to add any document errorObject " +errorObject);
        });
    }
```

When running in Android the JSONStore creation fails.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/worklight/jsonstore/util/JSONStoreUtil;
    01-08 13:34:03.962 12289-12425/com.DCSSMobileApp W/System.err:     at com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.dispatchers.BaseActionDispatcher.<init>(BaseActionDispatcher.java:44)
    01-08 13:34:03.962 12289-12425/com.DCSSMobileApp W/System.err:     at com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.dispatchers.BaseDatabaseActionDispatcher.<init>(BaseDatabaseActionDispatcher.java:29)
    01-08 13:34:03.962 12289-12425/com.DCSSMobileApp W/System.err:     at com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.dispatchers.AllDirtyActionDispatcher.<init>(AllDirtyActionDispatcher.java:36)
    01-08 13:34:03.962 12289-12425/com.DCSSMobileApp W/System.err:     at com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.StoragePlugin.initialize(StoragePlugin.java:59)
    01-08 13:34:03.962 12289-12425/com.DCSSMobileApp W/System.err:     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.privateInitialize(CordovaPlugin.java:50)
    01-08 13:34:03.962 12289-12425/com.DCSSMobileApp W/System.err:     at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.getPlugin(PluginManager.java:195)
    01-08 13:34:03.962 12289-12425/com.DCSSMobileApp W/System.err:     at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:141)
    01-08 13:34:03.962 12289-12425/com.DCSSMobileApp W/System.err:     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:61)
    01-08 13:34:03.962 12289-12425/com.DCSSMobileApp W/System.err:     at org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:40)
    01-08 13:34:03.962 12289-12425/com.DCSSMobileApp W/System.err:     at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
    01-08 13:34:03.962 12289-12425/com.DCSSMobileApp W/System.err:     at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:37)
    01-08 13:34:03.962 12289-12425/com.DCSSMobileApp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    01-08 13:34:03.962 12289-12425/com.DCSSMobileApp W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    01-08 13:34:03.962 12289-12425/com.DCSSMobileApp W/System.err:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
    01-08 13:34:03.962 12289-12425/com.DCSSMobileApp W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.worklight.jsonstore.util.JSONStoreUtil" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.DCSSMobileApp-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.DCSSMobileApp-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    01-08 13:34:03.964 12289-12425/com.DCSSMobileApp W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    01-08 13:34:03.964 12289-12425/com.DCSSMobileApp W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    01-08 13:34:03.964 12289-12425/com.DCSSMobileApp W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    01-08 13:34:03.964 12289-12425/com.DCSSMobileApp W/System.err:  ... 14 more
    01-08 13:34:03.964 12289-12425/com.DCSSMobileApp W/System.err:  Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.worklight.jsonstore.util.JSONStoreUtil
    01-08 13:34:03.965 12289-12425/com.DCSSMobileApp W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    01-08 13:34:03.965 12289-12425/com.DCSSMobileApp W/System.err:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
    01-08 13:34:03.965 12289-12425/com.DCSSMobileApp W/System.err:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
    01-08 13:34:03.965 12289-12425/com.DCSSMobileApp W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
    01-08 13:34:03.965 12289-12425/com.DCSSMobileApp W/System.err:      ... 15 more
    01-08 13:34:03.965 12289-12425/com.DCSSMobileApp W/System.err:  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: What is the build number of the MobileFirst Studio that you're using? Look in Eclipse > help > about > mobilefirst

Comment: Mobile First Plugin Studio 7.1.0.00-20151227-1725

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same build as mentioned in the comments and was able to successfully run JSONStore w/out encountering this error.

1. Create a new Hybrid app and added the Android environment
2. Added the JSONStore optional feature
3. Added the following code in common/js/main.js > `wlCommonInit()`:

   ```
   function wlCommonInit(){
       var collectionName = 'people';

       // Object that defines all the collections.
       var collections = {
           // Object that defines the 'people' collection.
           people : {
               // Object that defines the Search Fields for the 'people' collection.
              searchFields : {name: 'string', age: 'integer'}
           }
       };

       // Optional options object.
       var options = {
           // Optional username, default 'jsonstore'.
           username : 'carlos',

           // Optional password, default no password.
           password : '123',

           // Optional local key generation flag, default false.
           localKeyGen : false
       };

       WL.JSONStore.init(collections, options)

       .then(function () {
           alert ("success");
       });
   }
   ```

I launched the application in the Android Emulator and the alert displayed.

Comment: I am still getting the same error. I tried in different environment as well, also tried after clean-build the Android Environment still see the same issue.

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/worklight/jsonstore/util/JSONStoreUtil;

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working. I found that jsonstore.jar was not included in my Android project lib which caused this error.